# Unable to delete by range in SOLR

Tags: search, solr

I have an instance of SOLR 3.6 running, with JSON as the default updateHandler.

I am able to delete individual documents with the following:

```
curl "http://myURL/update?commit=true" -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{"delete": {"id":"1730887464"}}'
```

What is the right way to delete a range of IDs?

I have tried the following:

```
curl "http://myURL/update?commit=true" -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{"delete": {"id":"[* TO 1730887464]"}}'

curl "http://myURL/update?commit=true" -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{"delete": {"id":"[0 TO 1730887464]"}}'
```

And I get the following exception. Any help/pointers would be appreciated. 
I've looked up:

http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateJSON

http://lucene.apache.org/solr/api/doc-files/tutorial.html

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<title>Error 500 For input string: "[* TO 1730887464]"

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[* TO 1730887464]"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.                                                                                                             java:65)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:438)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:478)
        at org.apache.solr.schema.TrieField.readableToIndexed(TrieField.java:295                                                                                                             )
        at org.apache.solr.schema.TrieField.toInternal(TrieField.java:307)
        at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.delete(DirectUpdateHandle                                                                                                             r2.java:288)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processDelete(Run                                                                                                             UpdateProcessorFactory.java:68)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor.processDelete(Log                                                                                                             UpdateProcessorFactory.java:137)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.JsonLoader.processUpdate(JsonLoader.java:120)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.JsonLoader.load(JsonLoader.java:75)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(Co                                                                                                             ntentStreamHandlerBase.java:58)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandl                                                                                                             erBase.java:129)
        at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.handle                                                                                                             Request(RequestHandlers.java:244)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1376)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter                                                                                                             .java:365)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilte                                                                                                             r.java:260)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Servlet                                                                                                             Handler.java:1212)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:3                                                                                                             99)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.jav                                                                                                             a:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:1                                                                                                             82)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:7                                                                                                             66)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHand                                                                                                             lerCollection.java:230)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.                                                                                                             java:114)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:1                                                                                                             52)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:54                                                                                                             2)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnectio                                                                                                             n.java:945)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.                                                                                                             java:228)
        at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.j                                                                                                             ava:582)
</title>
</head>
<body><h2>HTTP ERROR 500</h2>
<p>Problem accessing /solr/update. Reason:
<pre>    For input string: "[* TO 1730887464]"

java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "[* TO 1730887464]"
        at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.                                                                                                             java:65)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:438)
        at java.lang.Long.parseLong(Long.java:478)
        at org.apache.solr.schema.TrieField.readableToIndexed(TrieField.java:295                                                                                                             )
        at org.apache.solr.schema.TrieField.toInternal(TrieField.java:307)
        at org.apache.solr.update.DirectUpdateHandler2.delete(DirectUpdateHandle                                                                                                             r2.java:288)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.RunUpdateProcessor.processDelete(Run                                                                                                             UpdateProcessorFactory.java:68)
        at org.apache.solr.update.processor.LogUpdateProcessor.processDelete(Log                                                                                                             UpdateProcessorFactory.java:137)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.JsonLoader.processUpdate(JsonLoader.java:120)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.JsonLoader.load(JsonLoader.java:75)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.ContentStreamHandlerBase.handleRequestBody(Co                                                                                                             ntentStreamHandlerBase.java:58)
        at org.apache.solr.handler.RequestHandlerBase.handleRequest(RequestHandl                                                                                                             erBase.java:129)
        at org.apache.solr.core.RequestHandlers$LazyRequestHandlerWrapper.handle                                                                                                             Request(RequestHandlers.java:244)
        at org.apache.solr.core.SolrCore.execute(SolrCore.java:1376)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.execute(SolrDispatchFilter                                                                                                             .java:365)
        at org.apache.solr.servlet.SolrDispatchFilter.doFilter(SolrDispatchFilte                                                                                                             r.java:260)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(Servlet                                                                                                             Handler.java:1212)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:3                                                                                                             99)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.jav                                                                                                             a:216)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:1                                                                                                             82)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:7                                                                                                             66)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:450)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.handle(ContextHand                                                                                                             lerCollection.java:230)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerCollection.handle(HandlerCollection.                                                                                                             java:114)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:1                                                                                                             52)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:54                                                                                                             2)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.content(HttpConnectio                                                                                                             n.java:945)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseNext(HttpParser.java:756)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpParser.parseAvailable(HttpParser.java:218)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
        at org.mortbay.jetty.bio.SocketConnector$Connection.run(SocketConnector.                                                                                                             java:228)
        at org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool$PoolThread.run(QueuedThreadPool.j                                                                                                             ava:582)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you need to use a delete by query:

```
curl "http://myURL/update?commit=true" -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '{"delete": {"query":"id:[* TO 1730887464]"}}'
```

I don't work a lot with json so not sure if the 'query' part is right...but I guess you see what i mean